# Electrical field stimulation of neurons: what are commonly used stimulation protocols and which are physiological?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, experimental-design

I am doing a labproject with primary mouse nerve cultures (hippocampus and midbrain) and part of the experiments involve performing electrical field stimulation on these neurons.

For now we have decided on three different types of stimulation:

- 1 Hz for 20 sec (20 action potentials)
- 50 Hz for 2 sec (100 action potentials)
- 20 Hz for 2 sec (40 action potentials) which my promoter said was commonly used

I have been looking for (but not finding) other commonly stimulation protocols, especially those with physiological levels.

- Are the protocols I have chosen physiological or not (or under- or overstimulation) and why is this so? I assume neuronal subtype also might play a part in this.
- Are there other commonly accepted paradigms for electrical field stimulation of neurons?
- How can I stimulate my cells within physiological levels?

Any advice, explanation and or further references to find answers to these questions are appreciated!

Comment: I think this question is much too broad to answer here - you are better off consulting with people in your lab and reading the literature. Appropriate stimulus paradigms depend entirely on what you are trying to accomplish, and defining them as "physiological" is always going to be context-dependent.

Comment: I agree with @BryanKrause that your question is not specific enough. We would need to know what you want to accomplish. Furthermore, while someone may present an argument about what is physiological for the intact hippocampus in a living animal under certain conditions, it is not at all clear to me that any boundaries make sense for cultured neurons beyond perhaps extremely high frequencies (say >300Hz) applied for a prolonged period of time.